# Error starting Kafka connect in distributed mode

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am starting Kafka connect in distribute mode but getting the following error.
This works fine on my other dev cluster, however, I only get this error in my production cluster.

```
ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed:84)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: "uri" parameter is null.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.uri.internal.JerseyUriBuilder.uri(JerseyUriBuilder.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.uri.internal.JerseyUriBuilder.uri(JerseyUriBuilder.java:48)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:83)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer.advertisedUrl(RestServer.java:347)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer.initializeServer(RestServer.java:218)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.startConnect(ConnectDistributed.java:99)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:78)
```

Following is the content of the connect.properties file that I am using

```
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
task.shutdown.graceful.timeout.ms=10000
offset.flush.interval.ms=60000
offset.flush.timeout.ms=5000
plugin.path=<directory path>
bootstrap.servers=<kafka-address>
group.id=Kafka_Connect_Group1
offset.storage.topic=<topic name>
offset.storage.replication.factor=2
config.storage.topic=<topic name>
config.storage.replication.factor=2
status.storage.topic=D<topic name>
status.storage.replication.factor=2
rest.host.name=
rest.port=20831
rest.advertised.host.name=
rest.advertised.port=20831
```

Comment: are `rest.host.name` and `rest.advertised.host.name` empty? or are you passing some private value? anyway, it seems that it might be something wrong with whatever you are passing in there

Comment: Error at `RestServer.advertisedUrl`... You need an advertised hostname

Comment: @OneCricketeer;  @BogdanSucaciu
I have set the empty values in my dev clusters and still it was working. 
I am running only once instance of the connector. Do we still need the advertised.host.name.?

Comment: what should be the value? I ran into the similar issue but while running kakfa-connect inside the docker image. I could kick off Kafka connect rest API on the machine directly